# Fitting html list to parent element height

Tags: html, css, list, height, html-lists

Alright, well describing this problem is very simple.

http://gflclan.com/gamemann/screenshots/Screenshot_09-15-14-17-06-10.png

I want that black hover color to fit the height of the divider. I know there have been questions asked about this before but I tried their solutions and it just isn't working.

Here's my CSS code:

```
#navbar {
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-right: 20%;
    background-image: url('navbg.png');
    border-radius:15px 15px 0px 0px;
    padding:1px 1px 1px 1px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #121212;
    height: auto;
}


#navbar ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

#navbar ul li {
    font-size: 150%;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-left: 30px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
}

#navbar ul li a {
    text-decoration:none;
}

#navbar li:hover{
    background-color: black;
}
```

This may be an easy fix, but I cannot figure it out.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

HTML Code:

```
    <body>
    <div id="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li onmouseover="playmsound()"><a href="">Home</a></li>
            <li onmouseover="playmsound()"><a href="">GFL</a></li>
            <li onmouseover="playmsound()"><a href="">Forums</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Thanks,

Roy (Gamemann)

Comment: And where is your *divider* ?? Can you share the HTML?

Comment: Also, if you're using the backgroud image just for the gradient, it would be much lighter if you used http://css-tricks.com/css3-gradients/

Comment: I edited the original post to add in the HTML code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

**css**

```
#navbar {
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-right: 20%;
    background-image: url('navbg.png');
    border-radius:15px 15px 0px 0px;
    padding:1px 1px 1px 1px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #121212;
    height: auto;
}
#navbar ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#navbar ul li {
    font-size: 150%;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-left: 30px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
    height: 75px;
    width: 1%;
}
#navbar ul li a {
    text-decoration:none;
}
#navbar li:hover {
    background-color: black;
}
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/0go4325t/6/)